# Why does my C random number generator only return "42"?

Tags: c, linux, random

As awesome an accidental feature as this is, it makes for a lousy way to "shuffle" an array of "cards". The fact that I'm getting the same number tells me I've having some problem in picking separate seeds each time. Am I using `srand48` or the `time(NULL)` call improperly?  Is there some underlying logic flaw I'm missing? Is there just not enough time inbetween iterations for the value of `time()` to be different?

The code is being run on Linux.

```
void shuffle()

{
  int i_rnd;   /* Integer random number, range 0..100 */
  int i_rnd2;
  card tempCard; /*temporary card to facillitate swapping*/
  int i = 0; /*can't use a FOR loop 'cause we're not using c99 standard*/
  while(i < 1000)
  {

      srand48( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );  /* Seed the random number generator */
      i_rnd = (int) ( drand48() * 100);
      i_rnd = i_rnd%52; // return a random number 0-51    
      i_rnd2 = (int) ( drand48() * 100);
      i_rnd2 = i_rnd2%52; // return a random number 0-51
      /*we have two random numbers, now exchange the two objects with the
      / picked array indices */
      tempCard =  cardDeck[i_rnd];
      cardDeck[i_rnd]=cardDeck[i_rnd2];
      cardDeck[i_rnd2]=tempCard;
      //swap complete. increment counter so we can eventually get out of the while
      i++;

  }

return;

}
```

Comment: 42 is the answer to life, the universe, and everything.

Comment: The program is giving you **the** answer without going through the steps needlessly. I wish I had a computer like yours.

Comment: @Mike you beat me to the joke!

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php

Comment: @Andrew Cooper Let's say... "how many roads must a man walk down?" and call it a millenia.

Comment: @belisarius:  LOL.  Q: To be or not to be?  A: 42.  It's amazing what you can come up with by combining literary sources.  And now that we know both the question and the answer, the universe will disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarrely inexplicable.  Or has this already happened?  ;-)

Comment: @Andrew Ask your nearest dolphin :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to seed the pseudorandom number generator *once*, not every time you use it.

Many (most?) pseudorandom number generators (PRNG) are deterministic given a certain seed value.  If `time()` returns the same value each time your loop executes, you seed the PRNG with the same value just before you use it each time, so when you query it for random numbers it returns the same values.

Comment: Ah. I'll move it outside the while loop then. That makes sense.

Comment: @Raven:  It's probably better to seed the PRNG in `main()` or in some function called from `main()`.  You want to seed it exactly once each time you run your program.

Comment: @Raven: No, move it to your `main()`. You don't want to seed every time you shuffle, either.

Answer (score 5):

Because you're seeding your random number generator every time through the loop with the same seed (it runs in less than a second). Call `srand48()` ONCE at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The PRNG is always deterministic...The randomness of PRNG is not attained by the Logic of it but by the seed it uses.

Therefore make that Seed as Random as possible inorder to achieve Randomness.