# Drand48 always returning 0 for first element? (C)

Tags: c, list

For some reason when I try to make an array and fill it up with random numbers generated by drand48, the first element will always be 0. Code is run like ./exec size. Can someone please help me out?

```
int matrixSize = atoi(argv[1]);
double vect[matrixSize];
printf("THIS IS NVECTOR-----------------------\n");
for(k = 0; k < matrixSize; ++k){
    vect[k] = drand48();
    printf("%f\n", vect[k]);
}
srand48(time(NULL));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my C random number generator only return "42"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893706/why-does-my-c-random-number-generator-only-return-42)

Comment: I'm surprised you don't see that your array is always the same (beyond even the first element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `srand48()` *before* calling `drand48()`. From t[he manpage for `drand48()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/drand48.3.html):

> The srand48(), seed48() and lcong48() functions are initialization
>   functions, one of which should be called before using drand48(),
>   lrand48() or mrand48().

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `srand48()` before the call to `drand48()`.  After any particular call to `srand48()`, `drand48()` will give the same sequence.

So using time to get and unpredictable `srand48()` seed will give the overall appearance of randomness.  But only if you do this *before* repeatedly calling `drand48()`.

Comment: Also make sure to only call `srand48` once